# Npm install error, silly fetchpackagemetadata error for request to http://registry.npmjs.org/concurrently failed, reason: socket hang up

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, sockets, npm

i am getting below errors:

"silly fetchpackagemetadata error for request to http://registry.npmjs.org/concurrently failed, reason: socket hang up"

i am behind corporate proxy. firewall is off

here is my settings:
command: npm config get proxy =
result: https://myproxy:8080 
command: npm config get registry =
result: http://registry.npmjs.org
command: npm config get key =
result: true 
command: npm cache clean

also set proxy using:
npm config set proxy http://myproxy:8080

i am getting bellow error: 
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for typescript@~2.1.0 request to http://registry.npmjs.org/typescript failed, reason: socket hang up

18 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for tslint@^3.15.1 request to http://registry.npmjs.org/tslint failed, reason: socket hang up

62 verbose node v8.11.0
63 verbose npm  v5.6.0
64 error code ECONNRESET
65 error errno ECONNRESET
66 error network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcommon failed, reason: socket hang up
67 error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
67 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
67 error network
67 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
67 error network 'proxy' conhttps://myproxy:8080fig is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

if i set proxy http://myproxy:8080 "http" without "s" it show below erro 
npm ERR! code E407 npm ERR! 407 Proxy Authentication Required: @angular/common@~4.3.4
i am stuck in this error, not able to find solution, i did googling 2-3 days tried many setting.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your provider or corporate proxy - it does not support a large number of open sessions when requesting NPM packets.

Decision:

- use another provider;
- set up a corporate proxy;
- try use a SOCKS5 proxy or VPN.

Answer (score -1):

npm was down for some hours today. That's the reason.

Check - https://status.npmjs.org

Comment: i have already mentioned that i am struggling from last 2-3 day. check last line "i did googling 2-3 days tried many setting."

Comment: Can you try `npm cache clean && npm cache clear`, `npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"`, `rm -rf node_modules/`, `npm install` in order?

Comment: hi vickey4 i have already tried these commands and mentioned in my post

Comment: Can you try updating `npm` using `npm update npm -g` and try the above commands in the mentioned order?